# Does copy command not accept variable on command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, copy

How can I use a variable in batch file for copy command to provide path for root folder?

```
set destination= "c:\destination folder"
mkdir %destination%

SET source = "C:\source folder\"
SET source_full = "C:\source folder\simple file.txt"

rem this doesn't work
copy %source%\"simple file.txt" %destination%

rem this works
copy %source_full% %destination%
```

Comment: Try `copy "%source%\simple file.txt" %destination%`

Comment: @DanielF That didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry misread initially...
Do not use spaces when setting variables then this...

```
copy %source%\"simple file.txt" %destination%
```

becomes this

```
copy %source%"simple file.txt" %destination%
```

Note your source already has a "\" and you added one outside of your quotes.
So calling that copy command was actually doing something weird with the extra slash.

Comment: Initially misread the question, though it was related to the copy command, but it's related to the synthax. Fixed the answer, refresh.

Comment: @zar fixed the comment.

Comment: Great it works, I deleted earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can't put a space between the variable and the `=`

```
C:\Users\glennjackman>set destination= "c:\destination folder"

C:\Users\glennjackman>echo %destination%
 "c:\destination folder"

C:\Users\glennjackman>SET source = "C:\source folder\"

C:\Users\glennjackman>echo %source%
%source%

C:\Users\glennjackman>SET source= "C:\source folder\"

C:\Users\glennjackman>echo %source%
 "C:\source folder\"
```

And it appears that quoting should include the variable name:

```
C:\Users\glennjackman>set "destination=c:\destination folder"

C:\Users\glennjackman>SET "source=C:\source folder"

C:\Users\glennjackman>copy "%source%\simple file.txt" "%destination%"
        1 file(s) copied.
```

Comment: Wow this is very counter-intuitive but it works! And yes no space on either side of the = sign is must otherwise it does't work!

Comment: Please don't delete your answer since it works but has a strange syntax. I have accepted the [other](https://superuser.com/a/1499349/475817) answer now since it has better syntax and the space on either side of = is also fine there!